# How are you supposed to post code in answer comments?

Tags: support, code

Answer comments are obviously not the right place to paste code. However in discussion it may be useful to refer to some code, for example a candidate implementation of something. Where are you supposed to post the code? An external service like Github gist?

My use case is the following: I used an answer to write a short program, and I'd like to post the result as a thank you to the answerer, and also for future reference.

**Edit**: based on the (poor) feedback I got here, my conclusion is to use an external provider such as GitHub gists.

Comment: I don't see why placing some code inside of a comment is a bad thing. `(function(){ /* this is an IIFE */ })()` I mean, assuming you have code that is relevant it seems the proper place to do that. Aside from simply placing it in your answer or question body, but I would assume you are asking about posts which are not yours.

Comment: *"as a thank you to the answerer"* - just up vote, or accept if it was your question. Speaking for myself, I'm sure people are off building things based on my answers, but I don't need to *see* them! *"also for future reference"* - whose? Will it help the next person with a similar question (then it should be an answer)? Or do you just want to share what you've done (then SO isn't really the right place for it)?

Answer (score 14):

You're really *not*.

If a conversation starts requiring code, then it may be a good idea to move that off to Chat as opposed to having it in the answer.  It also depends on what is being asked; be vigilant for [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) in which a user is attempting to get you to code the entirety of a solution for them.

---

Since you've clarified your use case, I'll say that this scenario is more of an exceptional case than the norm; normally one expects you to [pay it forward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as a way of saying "thanks", instead of including the source code you had written.  If it's the case that you had added your *own* code in addition to an answer's code, then that can stand on its own as an answer, so it should ideally be  added as an answer.

I do want to caution you that adding code just to say "thanks" is frowned upon, so you should only do that when you've got more than an answerer's code to add in.  Also, I'd caution you to avoid adding a lot of code; it's great that you've got your project working, but pasting all of the working code here doesn't add any value.

Comment: So your stance here is that users are not supposed to post code inside of comments whatsoever?

Comment: Keep it to a minimum; if you have to post *a lot* of code you don't want to be doing that in a comments box.

Comment: @Travis Note that you can format a single line of code by surrounding it with backticks

Comment: As often with SO, the answer to a perceived need is to deny it, with little or no supportive argumentation. Plus my question got downvoted. What a nice community! Anyways, I tried to ask!

Comment: _the answer to a perceived need is to deny it_ - @static_rtti You didn't tag your question as a feature request. Your question read as, "How do I do X?" not, "We should be able to do X, can this be added?".

Comment: @BSMP : That's because I was expecting a straightforward answer to a common need.

Comment: @static_rtti:  I'm not sure what the need is exactly.  Since you've changed around your question a bit, I'll go ahead and revise my answer so that it reads a bit clearer for a situation like this.

Comment: The need is that adding code is a nice, specific complement to a good answer. This will be my last comment in this thread since discussion is clearly not welcome here.

Answer (score 7):

Couldn't you add your code as a new answer? You can still upvote and accept the answer that inspired it, and reference that answer in your answer.

As a clarification based on a comment, a question can have more than one useful answer. Adding Answer B with a code implementation based on Answer A in no way detracts from A as long as A is acknowledged in B. A keeps its upvotes and its status as the accepted answer. People who happen to read B first will see a link to A. Depending on the reader's situation tested code, explanatory text, or both may be useful and should be upvoted accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that would be fair to the person who provided the correct answer. Plus text is often a better answer than a page of code.

Comment: @static_rtti - How is up voting and accepting their answer unfair to them? Also, this solution is fairly common. It's not unusual for an Asker to feel their code differed enough from the answer they used to warrant being posted as an answer.